# Extract number and text from a specific text format

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text similar to this:

> Hello @[123456:Foo]

How to get '123456' and 'Foo' ?

My attempt:

```
@\[([\d+]):([\s+])\]
```

Comment: Why vote down ?

Comment: Most probably because you didn't show your efforts on solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I have added my current solution ([\d+])([\s+])

Comment: You also failed to provide a list of examples that should be and shouldn't be matched including any unusual edge cases. There are numerous expressions to match what you want for that particular case but they may not be general enough to apply to your problem.

Comment: You are not looking for `:` and `\s` means whitespaces. Try `(\d+):(\w+)`

Comment: That is an extremely poor attempt at a solution, nowhere near matching.

Comment: I'm not good at regex sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
@\[(\d+):([^][]*)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0TfrvS/1). The values you need are in Group 1 and 2.

**Details**

- `@\[`  - a `@[` substring
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `([^][]*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char.

C# demo:

```
var m = Regex.Match(str, @"@\[(\d+):([^][]*)]");
if (m.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: SO still lacks the "Auto-accept Regex answers from Wiktor" feature .